# Weird issue with a sql query

Tags: mysql

i'm stuck on a sql query -

```
select * from api_runner group by channel order by id_queue asc
```

What i'm essentially trying to do, is group by the channel, and return the first row for this channel itself

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACtQb.png)

However, for some reason, the row it returns seems to be completely randomized

[Returned Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xtgJ.png)

instead of returning id_queue  1
it returns id_queue 2 instead?

Comment: This is correct behavior, all non-aggregated fields in a group by are "whatever value we came across and stuck with", and in no way guaranteed to be from any particular row (other than the row values of the grouping fields match).

Comment: `SELECT r.* FROM ( SELECT q.channel, MIN(q.id_queue) AS id_queue FROM api_runner q GROUP BY q.channel) m JOIN api_runner r ON r.channel = m.channel AND r.id_queue = m.id_queue ORDER BY ...`

Comment: @spencer7593 this worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: The behavior is not weird. It's a documented MySQL specific extension to the SQL standard. What's weird is that MySQL does not enable (by default) `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in sql_mode to make MySQL (by default) conform to the standard, and throw an "non-aggregate column in SELECT list not in GROUP BY" type error.

Comment: For the example query in my comment, note that if two or more rows with the same `channel` have the same minimum `id_queue` value, the query will return both of the rows. If `id_queue` is guaranteed to be unique for a given `channel`, this isn't an issue.